# How to get Concrete Block?

Tags: starbound

I'm trying to create a settlement made by [Outpost Concrete](http://starbounder.org/Outpost_Concrete), but unfortunately I can't create more of it because I'm missing the recipe for the [Concrete Block](http://starbounder.org/Concrete_Block).

[image]

According to the wiki, I can learn the recipe by picking up a concrete block, which is supposedly found in dungeons, but so far I did not find any concrete in the dungeons I visited.

So far I've been in these types of dungeons:

- Apex Laboratory
- Hylotl Underwater City
- Human Prison

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found it in an Apex Rebel Camp in the underground bunkers. Mine was on a Gentle Star > Desert World > Rainbow biome.

[image: Concrete Block]

Comment: Also the foundation of Miniknog cities!

Comment: I also managed to find in a Hyotl underwater base, but I had to switch of the generator first to mine it.